# Difference between std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a novice in c++. I have come across the usage of std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr in my code

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<type1> type1Handler;
typedef std::shared_ptr<type2> type2Handler;
```

I have two questions:

1. What is the advantage of using `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`
2. What is the prime difference among them?

Possibly an example would be much helpful!

Comment: Did you try google at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are for 2 completely different use cases.

1. `std::unique_ptr` retains **sole** ownership of an object and destroys that object when the unique_ptr goes out of scope. No two `unique_ptr`'s instances can manage the same object. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)
2. `std::shared_ptr` retains **shared** ownership of an object. Several `shared_ptr` objects may own the same object. The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when the last remaining `shared_ptr` owning the object is destroyed or the last remaining `shared_ptr` owning the object is assigned another pointer via `operator=` or `reset()`. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

To enforce the sole ownership `std::unique_ptr` is non-assignable and non-copyable. This means you have to use move semantics with it.

If you see the `unique_ptr` somewhere in the code this means that **Look, here is the pointer and we own it!**. This cannot be said about `shared_ptr`, where ownership can be dispersed all around the code.

Answer (score 3):

`std::unique_ptr`:

> [std::unique_ptr is a smart pointer that retains sole ownership of an object through a pointer and destroys that object when the unique_ptr goes out of scope. No two unique_ptr instances can manage the same object.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

`std::shared_ptr`:

> [std::shared_ptr is a smart pointer that retains shared ownership of an object through a pointer. Several shared_ptr objects may own the same object.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)